# how to retrieve COD file from ALX file?

Tags: blackberry

I am able to retrieve information in cod files from jad files but if i want to retrieve same information about COD file from alx file then how it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Alx file is an xml file. Parse this xml file and get the information.

Comment: sorry sir but i think u didnt understand my question but by parsing that xml file i will get the name of cod file only and not the contents i am asking about contents e.g.in jad file we will get contents from cod file RIM-COD-SHA1-4: 35 c3 0e 6d 9f 1e e6 05 92 6e ff fc bb f4 af b1 20 fd 0e fd as in hash format i want that type of contnet from alx file also

Comment: why did you suppose that this information is stored into alx-file ? It is not true. Alx file does not contain such information.